# Can't load Ubuntu 17.04

Tags: linux, ubuntu

After updating my OS, i can't start it. It load and have no errors when it load. But when it load to ask me password, it has black screen, some times show me a mouse cursor and window with wifi connection. What's going on? 
My laptop is Lenovo g710

Comment: so, the problem was resolved by reinstalling OS

Comment: Down-voted because questions about general computing hardware and software are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve tools used primarily for programming. You may be able to get help on [Super User](https://superuser.com/).

Comment: Sorry, i'm understanded

Comment: No problem :) I'm sure you would have gotten better help there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to boot Ubuntu in Recovery Mode (the second boot option in GRUB)

Comment: I was try, it don't help